# ASP.NET MVC Best Implementation Practices

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've recently been asked to completely rewrite and redesign a web site and the owner of the company has stressed that he wants the site to be made with the latest and greatest technology available, but to avoid additional costs.

As of right now, I'm torn between looking into a CMS implementation and writing a new implementation with MVC.

The site is mainly brochure ware, but will need to allow the visitors to submit some data through forms.  There are quite a few lists and content features that are dynamic and should be treated as such.  Since ASP.NET MVC is new, I don't want to bastardize the implementation if I go that way...

Any recommendations on best implementation practices for a MVC website?  Also, has anyone had their MVC implementation hosted anywhere that they would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also [ASP.Net Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/) to be considered. You can use both MVC and DD together. SHanselman has [a nice article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) on how this can work out.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.sharparchitecture.net/

Comment: That link is dead, but it's now here: http://sharparchitecture.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

By far I think [Who Can Help Me](http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com) is an excellent implementation of ASP.NET MVC

I also think these are good coding examples to look at:

- [Sharp Architecture](http://www.sharparchitecture.net/) (Who Can Help Me utilizes some of this framework)
- [MVC Turbine](http://mvcturbine.codeplex.com/)

Some others that are also good (once you've gone through the above).

- [N2CMS](http://n2cms.com)  Content management System
- [BlogService (AtomSite)](http://atomsite.net) Blogging Engine
- [Orchard CMS](http://orchard.codeplex.com) Content Management System