# Tips and Tricks about Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Can any one Tell me

best way to structure Asp.net mvc application.? best tips and tricks?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate [asp-net-mvc-best-implementation-practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/715968/asp-net-mvc-best-implementation-practices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[www.asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) is the perfect place for you. It contains samples and walthroughs. Take a look at the Music store sample. It's probably better to start using version 3 if you have the possibility!